# Неправильная работа float в IE11

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, float

Есть сайт. http://audi-a6.org/hospital-israel/

Почему-то блок с контактами в *IE11* уезжает в правую сторону, хотя ему задано свойство `float:left`. Из-за этого и остальные блоки отображаются не правильно.

Вот часть кода:

```css
a {
    color: #2361A1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-wrapper {
    max-width: 1028px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left-sidebar {
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 195px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
.widget-head, .widget-head-contact {
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #054b9a;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.left-sidebar .widget-body, .defo .widget-body {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.left-sidebar .widget-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
}
.left-sidebar .widget-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0;
}
.left-sidebar .widget-body .widget-list-item::before {
    content: "✓ ";
    color: green;
}

.main-content > h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.main-content h1, .main-content h2, .main-content h3 {
    color: #0852A5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper clearfix">
  <aside class="left-sidebar">
    <div class="widget">
      <div class="widget-head">
        <h3>Почему Израиль?</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="textwidget">
        <div class="widget-body">
          <ul class="widget-list">
            <li class="widget-list-item">Видимая результативность лечения</li>
            <li class="widget-list-item">Известные и опытные врачи</li>
            <li class="widget-list-item">Правильно подобранные программы</li>
            <li class="widget-list-item">Адекватные цены на лечение от клиник <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-head">
        <h3>Скорая помощь</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="textwidget">
        <div class="widget-body">
          <p>ВРЕМЯ решает все!Воспользуйтесь услугами санитарной авиации для спасения близких. <a href="#">Подробнее</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <section class="main-content">
    <h1>Лечение в Израиле</h1>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Если Вы столкнулись с серьезным заболеванием, очень важно обратиться за помощью в надежное медицинское учреждение с безупречной репутацией. К таковым относятся известные клиники Израиля: «Университетская Больница Хадасса», «Клиника Ассута», «Онкологический
      центр Давидоф», «Белинсон» и др.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Будучи официальными представителями указанных медицинских центров, мы предлагаем стать Вашим партнером в борьбе с недугом. Мы поможем подобрать для Вас индивидуальный курс лечения в одной из клиник Израиля, а также окажем помощь в организации Вашего
      приезда в страну.</p>
    <p>
      <a name="Лечение-в-Израиле"></a>
    </p>
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Лечение в Израиле – это:</strong></h2>
    <ul style="text-align: justify;">
      <li><strong>Гарантия эффективности диагностики и лечения различных </strong><a href="http://hospital-israel.ru/otdeleniya/bolezni/"><strong>видов заболеваний</strong></a>. Диагностика и лечение, проводимые в клиниках Израиля, соответствуют высочайшим
        мировым стандартам.</li>
      <li><a href="http://hospital-israel.ru/israelidoctors/"><strong>Специалисты</strong></a><strong> самых разнообразных профилей </strong>готовы оказать Вам качественную медицинскую помощь. Медицинский персонал авторитетных клиник Израиля – это опытные
        высококвалифицированные специалисты.</li>
      <li><strong>Современное оснащение клиник Израиля. </strong>Компании именно этой страны составляют 30% мировых лидеров по поставкам новейшего медицинского оборудования.</li>
      <li><strong>Все </strong><a href="http://hospital-israel.ru/lechenie-v-izraile-procedury/"><strong>виды процедур</strong></a><strong> диагностики и лечения. </strong>В клиниках Израиля Вам будет предложены комплексные программы лечения, включающие различные
        виды процедур.</li>
      <li><strong>Русскоговорящий персонал </strong>всегда откликнется на Вашу просьбу и поможет освоиться на новом месте.</li>
      <li><strong>Благоприятный климат Израиля</strong>, огромное количество <strong>достопримечательностей</strong>, а также <strong>гостеприимные жители</strong> страны скрасят процесс Вашего выздоровления.</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tablepress-1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
      <div class="dataTables_info" id="tablepress-1_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 29 of 29 entries</div>
    </div>
    <!-- #tablepress-1 from cache -->
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Преимущества Медицинской Международной Службы:</strong></h2>
    <ul style="text-align: justify;">
      <li><strong>Прозрачные цены </strong>– наше основное правило. Мы готовы помочь Вам сориентироваться в стоимости процедур, чтобы Вы избежали ненужных трат.</li>
      <li><strong>Круглосуточная онлайн помощь </strong>– задайте вопросы сотруднику нашей службы.</li>
      <li><strong>Помощь в организации Вашего приезда в Израиль. </strong>Мы поможем Вам забронировать билет на самолёт, окажем визовую поддержку, обеспечим трансфер из аэропорта, забронируем для Вас комфортный, приемлемый по стоимости и удобно расположенный
        отель.</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">
      <img class="alignleft wp-image-9461" title="israel russian flags" src="http://hospital-israel.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/israel-russian-flags.jpg" alt="" width="190" height="150">В прошлом году более 40,000 жителей СНГ приехали на лечение в Израиле. Для выбора Израиля, как страны, где можно получить помощь, есть множество причин: отсутствия языкового барьера, мягкий климат, возможности курортного лечения и так далее. Однако
      главная причина, почему стоит отправиться лечиться именно в Израиле – <strong>это высокая &nbsp;РЕЗУЛЬТАТИВНОСТЬ лечения</strong>.</p>
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;">Менталитет:</h2>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Приезжая в Израиль Вы приезжаете в солнечную страну на берегу средиземного моря, где 20% населения выходцы из СНГ. Здесь не просто разговаривают на русском языке, здесь понимают Ваш менталитет, Ваши переживания, ожидания и просто понимают по-человечески.
      Такого уровня понимания вряд ли можно достичь в клиниках Германии или Франции (где, кстати, лечение стоит дороже).</p>
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;">Новые виды Лечения:</h2>
    <p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Израиль</strong> – это маленькая страна, в которой нет полезных ископаемых. <strong>Наш главный экспорт</strong> – это научные разработки. <strong>30% компаний на бирже NASDAQ</strong> из Израиля и это больше чем из любой другой страны. Большинство
      этих компаний – <strong>медицинские</strong>. В Израиле разработали многие методы лечение, которые потом перенимаются другими странами и становятся стандартом медицинского качества. Здесь впервые в мире вылечили «неизлечимых» больных с нейродегенеративными
      заболеваниями. Здесь поняли и продемонстрировали, как лечить рак кожи и многие <a title="Отделения" href="http://hospital-israel.ru/otdeleniya/">другие заболевания</a>.</p>
    <h2 style="text-align: justify;">Боевые врачи:</h2>
    <p style="text-align: justify;"><a title="Врачи в Израиле" href="/israelidoctors/">Наши врачи</a> обучаются в ведущих университетах планеты, проходят стажировку в госпиталях Америки и участвуют в передовых научных исследованиях. Наших врачей не просто так называют боевыми врачами.
      Из-за специфики нашей страны многие врачи являются офицерами Израильской армии, и они работали в самых сложнейших боевых условиях. Наши врачи вытягивали больных людей из ситуаций, где шансы были равны практически нулю.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Вывод один:</strong> если есть хоть какая-то возможность спасти и вылечить человека – израильский врач за нее ухватится и будет по настоящему бороться за здоровье этого человека. Бывают и такие ситуации, когда надеятся можно только на чудо
      и оно, здесь, в библейской стране – близко.</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Время решает все, не опаздывайте, не испытывайте судьбу – приезжайте на <span style="color: #000000;"><span style="color: #000000;">лечение в Израиль</span></span>.</strong>
    </p>
    <ul class="arrow">
      <p></p>
      <ul>
        <li><a title="Вопросы о Лечении в Израиле" href="http://hospital-israel.ru/israel-faq/"><strong>Часто задаваемые&nbsp;вопросы и&nbsp;ответы о Лечение в Израиле</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li><strong><a title="Контрольный перечень для лечения в Израиле" href="http://hospital-israel.ru/kontrolnyj-perechen-dlya-lecheniya-v-izraile/">Скачать контрольный перечень для лечение в Израиле</a></strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p></p>
    </ul>
    <p>Вы решили оставить заявку на лечение? Позвольте нам позаботиться о Вас.</p>
    <p>Обратитесь к нам прямо сейчас – и мы свяжемся с Вами в течение суток. Оставьте <a href="http://hospital-israel.ru/contacts-2/">заявку на лечение в Израиле</a> – остальные хлопоты мы берём на себя!</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Всегда ваша,</p>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Международная Медицинская Служба.</p>
  </section>
  <aside class="right-sidebar">
    <div class="widget">
      <div class="widget-head-contact">
        <h3>Контакты:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="textwidget">
        <div class="widget-body-contact">
          <ul class="widget-list">
            <li class="widget-list-item">Израиль: <a href="tel:+972547829585">+972547829585</a>
            </li>
            <li class="widget-list-item">Израиль: <a href="tel:+97233741349">+97233741349</a>
            </li>
            <li class="widget-list-item">Россия: <a href="tel:+74996385735">+74996385735</a>
            </li>
            <li class="widget-list-item">Украина: <a href="tel:+380947114836">+380947114836</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="textwidget"></div>

    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Фото проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было добавить свойство `clear:left` для класса .left-sidebar